# Round in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I have below SQL that returns the result, but I want the price to rounded to 6 decimal places.

```
select opt.blo,
  opt.premiumcurrency,
     case
      when opt.structurename is not null then opt.basemarketprice /100
        when pct = 1 then opt.basemarketprice /100
        when pct = 2 then opt.termmarketprice / opt.notional
        when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.premiumcurrency  then opt.basemarketprice /100
        else opt.termmarketpricepercent /100
    end as round(price,6)
from interafce opt
```

When I add below it gives me error

**ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are placing the `round()` function around the column alias, you need to place it around your `CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

The `case` needs to go into the `round()`.  You are confusing the function with the alias:

```
 round(case when opt.structurename is not null then opt.basemarketprice /100
            when pct = 1 then opt.basemarketprice /100
            when pct = 2 then opt.termmarketprice / opt.notional
            when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.premiumcurrency  then opt.basemarketprice /100
            else opt.termmarketpricepercent /100
       end, 6) as roundedPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

end as round(price,6) does'nt work.  You are aliasing the column as "round(price,6)"

rather do a

```
select .....
....
when opt.structurename is not null then round(opt.basemarketprice /100,6)
        when pct = 1 then round(opt.basemarketprice /100,6)
        when pct = 2 then round(opt.termmarketprice / opt.notional,6)
        when opt.notionalcurrency = opt.premiumcurrency  then round(opt.basemarketprice /100,6)
        else round(opt.termmarketpricepercent /100,6)
    end as rounded_price
```